# JHipster application creation problems

Tags: jhipster

When i try to create new application i receive this message

```
yarn install v1.5.1
info No lockfile found.
[1/5] Validating package.json...
[2/5] Resolving packages...
warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with 
requested version "source-map@^0.5.6"
```

I am sorry, i was not precise enough in stating my problem.
So, as i said i receive this message while creating new application.

After the process of creating new application is over i execute this command

```
./mvnw package -Pprod dockerfile:build
```

And then this is what i see:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------ 
 ------
[INFO] Building Jhipster Test Project 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------ 
------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:copy-resources (default- 
resources) @ jhipster-test-project ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] Copying 15 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:resources (default-resources) @ 
jhipster-test-project ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] Copying 15 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M1:enforce (enforce-versions) @ 
jhipster-test-project ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:copy-resources (docker-resources) 
@ jhipster-test-project ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.9:prepare-agent (pre-unit-tests) @ 
jhipster-test-project ---
[INFO] argLine set to -javaagent:/home/igor/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.9/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.9-runtime.jar=destfile=/home/igor/JHipsterProjects/jhipster-test-project/target/test-results/coverage/jacoco/jacoco.exec -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Xmx256m
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- git-commit-id-plugin:2.2.4:revision (default) @ jhipster-test-project ---
 [INFO] 
 [INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.9.RELEASE:build-info (default) @ jhipster-test-project ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:install-node-and-yarn (install node and yarn) @ jhipster-test-project ---
[INFO] Installing node version v8.9.4
[INFO] Unpacking /home/igor/.m2/repository/com/github/eirslett/node/8.9.4/node-8.9.4-linux-x64.tar.gz into /home/igor/JHipsterProjects/jhipster-test-project/node/tmp
[INFO] Copying node binary from /home/igor/JHipsterProjects/jhipster-test-project/node/tmp/node-v8.9.4-linux-x64/bin/node to /home/igor/JHipsterProjects/jhipster-test-project/node/node
[INFO] Installed node locally.
[INFO] Installing Yarn version v1.3.2
[INFO] Unpacking /home/igor/.m2/repository/com/github/eirslett/yarn/1.3.2/yarn-1.3.2.tar.gz into /home/igor/JHipsterProjects/jhipster-test-project/node/yarn
[INFO] Installed Yarn locally.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:yarn (yarn install) @ jhipster-test-project ---
[INFO] Running 'yarn install --force' in /home/igor/JHipsterProjects/jhipster-test-project
[INFO] yarn install v1.3.2
[INFO] [1/5] Validating package.json...
[INFO] [2/5] Resolving packages...
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.5.6"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.5.6"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.5.6"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@0.5.x"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.5.3"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.5.6"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@0.1.x"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.5.3"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.5.6"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.5.6"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@~0.4.1"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@0.5.x"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.5.7"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@~0.5.1"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.4.2"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.5.3"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.5.6"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.5.6"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.5.6"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.5.6"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@~0.5.0"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.5.3"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.5.1"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@~0.2.0"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.4.4"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.1.41"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.4.2"
[INFO] [3/5] Fetching packages...
[INFO] info fsevents@1.1.3: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
[INFO] info "fsevents@1.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[INFO] [4/5] Linking dependencies...
[ERROR] warning " > bootstrap@4.0.0" has unmet peer dependency 
"popper.js@^1.12.9".
[INFO] [5/5] Rebuilding all packages...
[INFO] success Saved lockfile.
[INFO] $ node node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/install.js
[INFO] Found PhantomJS at /home/igor/JHipsterProjects/jhipster-test-project/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs ...verifying
[INFO] PhantomJS is previously installed at /home/igor/JHipsterProjects/jhipster-test-project/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs
[INFO] Done in 9.71s.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:yarn (webpack build prod) @ jhipster-test-project ---
[INFO] yarn not inheriting proxy config from Maven
[INFO] Running 'yarn run webpack:prod' in /home/igor/JHipsterProjects/jhipster-test-project
[INFO] yarn run v1.3.2
[INFO] $ yarn run cleanup && yarn run webpack:prod:main && yarn run clean-www
[INFO] $ rimraf target/{aot,www}
[INFO] $ yarn run webpack -- --config webpack/webpack.prod.js --profile
[ERROR] warning From Yarn 1.0 onwards, scripts don't require "--" for options to be forwarded. In a future version, any explicit "--" will be forwarded as-is to the scripts.
[INFO] $ node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack/webpack.prod.js --profile
[INFO] MergetJsonsWebpackPlugin compilation started...
[INFO] MergetJsonsWebpackPlugin compilation completed...
[ERROR] buffer.js:202
[ERROR]   throw new TypeError(kFromErrorMsg);
[ERROR]   ^
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] TypeError: First argument must be a string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, 
Array, or array-like object.
[ERROR]     at Function.Buffer.from (buffer.js:202:9)
[ERROR]     at new Buffer (buffer.js:158:17)
[ERROR]     at writeOut (/home/igor/JHipsterProjects/jhipster-test-project/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:334:17)
[ERROR]     at require.forEach (/home/igor/JHipsterProjects/jhipster-test-project/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:345:12)
[ERROR]     at /home/igor/JHipsterProjects/jhipster-test-project/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3096:16
[ERROR]     at eachOfArrayLike (/home/igor/JHipsterProjects/jhipster-test-project/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1055:9)
[ERROR]     at eachOf (/home/igor/JHipsterProjects/jhipster-test-project/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1103:5)
[ERROR]     at Object.eachLimit (/home/igor/JHipsterProjects/jhipster-test-project/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3158:5)
[ERROR]     at emitFiles (/home/igor/JHipsterProjects/jhipster-test-project/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:315:21)
[ERROR]     at /home/igor/JHipsterProjects/jhipster-test-project/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:30:20
[ERROR]     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:135:15)
[ERROR] error Command failed with exit code 1.
enter code here[INFO] info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for 
documentation about this command.
[ERROR] error Command failed with exit code 1.
[INFO] info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
[ERROR] error Command failed with exit code 1.
[INFO] info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 42.200 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-03-07T23:12:19+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 32M/397M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:yarn (webpack build prod) on project jhipster-test-project: Failed to run task: 'yarn run webpack:prod' failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 
(Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
 [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

So my question is what could be a problem?

Comment: I don't see an issue that would stop the project generation.  The warning is just that - a warning.

Comment: And what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in JHipster 4.14.1, see https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/7188

Comment: I have updated JHipster, but now i have new problem:
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal pl.project13.maven:git-commit- 
    id-plugin:2.2.4:revision (default) on project jhipster: Could not 
    complete Mojo execution...: Error: Could not get HEAD Ref, are 
    you sure you have some commits in the dotGitDirectory? -> [Help 1]

Comment: Well, it seems that you don't have a valid git repository in your project folder or never committed to it. Fit it and build should work

Comment: Did you fix your problem?